# Draw progress bar and textview in content area of nine patch

Tags: android, styles, nine-patch

I have a `RelativeLayout` with a `ProgressBar` and a `TextView` nested inside. The background of the `RelativeLayout` is defined by a 9patch image, but the child views aren't properly obeying the content area of the 9patch image, instead they just appear where they would appear if I had no content area defined in my 9patch image.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@+drawable/loading_screen" 
    android:padding="0dip" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/loading"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my 9patch file:

[image: my 9patch file]

Answer (score 0):

The content area defined in 9patch image has absolutely nothing to do with where UI component will be, it just defines how the image should be stretched to fill the designated area. To make the UI component placement consistent with the 9patch image, you need to add appropriate padding to your `RelativeLayout`, by which I mean the left/right/top/bottom padding size should be the same as the four sides of your 9patch image.

Comment: I thought the whole point of the content area of the 9patch was to replace padding though? What does it do if not that?

Comment: I see what you are trying to do now, but according to Android doc (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch):  If a ***View object*** sets the NinePatch as its background and then specifies the View's text, it will stretch itself so that all the text fits inside only the area designated by the right and bottom lines (if included)... So it looks like it only works for View's, and not layouts.

Comment: RelativeLayout is a subclass of View though. Maybe it only applies to text and not child views.